# android button causes crash

Tags: android, button

This should be a very simple answer for anyone somewhat familiar with Android, I'm just getting started messing around with it. I've got two Views: main and other. Each view has a Button to switch Views. This is my Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.other);

    switcher = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    switcherListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.other);
        }
    };
    switcher.setOnClickListener(switcherListener);

    switcher2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    switcherListener2 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }
    };
    switcher2.setOnClickListener(switcherListener2);
}

private Button switcher, switcher2;
private View.OnClickListener switcherListener, switcherListener2;
```

The problem is that it doesn't even load, the Android emulator says it has stopped working. What do I change to make this work?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check the logcat for the stack trace and add it to your question. Otherwise we might not be able help you.

Comment: You should not use setContentView more than once per activity.

Comment: that would be my guess as a reason too. If that is not the cause it will be sooner or later...

Comment: post your logcat trace here

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `switcher2` is in a View this is not created yet `R.layout.main`, so when you call `switcher2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);` it is in a view that is not inflated yet. Try the following, but it is not good coding:

```
switcher = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    switcherListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.other);
            switcher2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            switcher2.setOnClickListener(switcherListener2);
        }
    };
    switcher.setOnClickListener(switcherListener);

    switcherListener2 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }
    };
```